# What is the meaning of "*=" in TSQL syntax?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I see the following syntax in a Sybase TSQL script I have to modify:

```
table1.Column1 *= table2.Column1
```

What does the `*=` portion of the syntax do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the old way of writing a LEFT OUTER JOIN, `=*` is a RIGHT OUTER JOIN

These two are the same

New ANSI JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM Test2 t2
LEFT JOIN Test1 t1
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Old JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM Test1 t1,Test2 t2
WHERE t1.id =* t2.id
```